# External linkage - what to do when there is a tie

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I am considering to implement a complete linkage clustering algorithm from scratch for study purposes. I've seen that there is a big difference when compared to single linkage:

> Unlike single linkage, the complete linkage method can be strongly affected by draw cases (where there are 2 groups/clusters with the same distance value in the distance matrix).

I'd like to see an example of distance matrix where this occurs and understand why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the 1-dimensional data set

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Depending how you do the first merges, you can get pretty good or pretty bad results. For example, first merge 2-3, 5-6 and 8-9. Then 2-3-4 and 7-8-9. Compare this to the "obvious" result that most humans would produce.